# Fixando vídeo do iframe ao rolar a página

Tags: iframe, youtube

Pessoal precisava implementar uma funcionalidade no meu `iframe` do youtube que inseri em meu site eu queria que quando rolasse a pagina aparecesse o meu frame do youtube fixo no canto direito da tela igual a desse site [aqui](http://www.novasmidias.com/) só que não faço ideia de como fazer e nem como pesquisar já que não sei o nome que dão a esse tipo de efeito alguém poderia me ajudar me passar algum link de documentação ou como fazer isso agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar jquery para fazer isso. Segue o exemplo que eu montei:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>StackOverflow</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            console.log("pronto");

            // evento quando o scrool é acionado
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                console.log($(window).scrollTop());

                // tamanho do scrool maior que 320px, adiciona class para reposicionar o vídeo
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > 320)
                    $("#frameVideo").addClass("positionRight");

                // tamanho do scrool em tamanho diferente que 320px, remove class para reposicionar o vídeo
                else 
                    $("#frameVideo").removeClass("positionRight");
            });

        });
    </script>

    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            height: 0px;
            height: 2000px;
        }

        .position {
            height: 300px;
            width: 600px;
            background-color: red;
        }

        .positionRight {
            position: fixed;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            height: 150px;
            width: 300px;
            background-color: blue !important;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="frameVideo" class="position"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: amigo o js adiciono no head ou no body no final da pagina

Comment: no head <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Adicionei o documento inteiro.

Answer (score 0):

Se for igual mesmo, deixa o wireframe como `position fixed`e posiciona ele com `right:0` e `bottom:0` esse valores você pode ajudar de acordo com o que ficar melhor

acho que é isso, só com css se resolve as coisas

**Mostrar apenas quando rolar o mouse**

Para isso terá de ser feito um evento para ouvir o scroll do usuário

Demonstração básica de como criar este evento

```
let ouvindoScroll = document.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
    console.log(e)
});
```

Fazendo o video aparecer depois de uma certa rolagem

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {

    if (window.scrollY > 300) {

        console.log("mostra video")

    } else {

        console.log("oculta video")

    }

});
```

Acho que daqui você já consegue seguir a diante ;)
Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Então amigo precisava igual o do link mesmo mais percebe que o mini video so apare quando ele rola a pagina é algum plugin especifico ou uma conf que faz dentro do proprio frame

Comment: Sim sim, vou editar minha resposta com essa informação tbm, desculpa

Comment: Pronto, vê se te ajuda